# regression model using tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, regression, data-science

I'd like to know what is a good model to do regression using tensorflow (I have around 200 columns on my train dataset)

The majority of the examples I find online are mainly for image classification , using convolution nets, which are not suitable (I think) for regression. The very few regression examples I find are simple Xw +b models which I implemented like so:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, train[cols].shape[1]])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([train[cols].shape[1], 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
preds = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
```

I tried several variations of the code bellow to add hidden layers but the result has always been worst

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, train[cols].shape[1]], name = 'X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name = 'Y')

hidden1  = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([train[cols].shape[1], 70], stddev=0.01), name = 'hidden1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1],stddev=0.01), name ='bias1')
...repeat for other layers....


X = tf.nn.dropout(X, p_keep_input)
h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, hidden1) + b1)

h = tf.nn.dropout(h, p_keep_hidden)
h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h, hidden2) +b2)


h2 = tf.nn.dropout(h2, p_keep_hidden)

preds =  tf.matmul(h2, w_o)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *the result has always been worst*?

Comment: There is no real difference in general (using NNs for classification/regression) except that you don't want to use some softmax as last activation (of course there are many decisions to be made; architecture and co). Take some usual MLP and use some output-dimension tailored for your task which is activated by Sigmoid or something similar. (The example of linear-regression you give is more a toy-model representing general-computation with theano. You can always port some classic non-NN regression-approaches to tensorflow; but the learning-algs will probably be not as good as tailored ones)